# Autocomplete error "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on an autocomplete that will bring you the data the moment you select one suggestion, but everytime I choose I get this error:

> "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#idt").autocomplete({
  source:'search.php',minLength:1,select: function(event,ui) {
    var idt=$("#idt").val(ui.item.label);
    $.post("show.php",{idt:idt},function(data){$('#reportes').html(data).hide().fadeIn(700);});
  }
   });

  });
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" name="idt" value="" id='idt' class="t_25p_25" placeholder="Ejemplo: 59">
```

I need to know what i'm doing wrong

Comment: `var idt=$("#idt").val(idt[ui.item.label]);` <= this would be my first point of investigation.  Changing the value of the element may some how be re-triggering the autocomplete.

Comment: Taplar sorry I posted an earlier version of the script, I updated it

Comment: `var idt=$("#idt").val(ui.item.label);` <= is still changing the value.  That would still be my first point of investigation.

Comment: I tried adding a return false after that, it fixes the error but it doesn't activate the post